Vocal recording difficulties with certain frequencies
I've been trying to record some vocals for a song on my laptop. It's the first time I've ever recorded vocals with my own laptop, and I've run into some problems.
I used two different mics to test my theory, but basically my laptop refuses to record certain frequencies. I'm using an LG Gram laptop, the software I used was Ableton 11 Lite, and I forgot which mics in particular, but one was a Rode and the other was a Shure.
To test this out, I used the same microphones on different laptops and the other ones worked. I also did an online mic test and tried testing a bunch of frequencies (I sang into the mic). I also sang the melody into my tuner on my phone, and the notes that cut out were around B# (roughly 250 Hz). What's also weird is that it can record frequencies/notes above and below that frequency.
Is there anything I can do to fix this problem?

Hi Gabe, you'd really need to pop a link to your audio file so we could take a look at it. Without that, we can't even guess what your setup is like and what issues may exist

Did you connect those microphones to the 3.5 mm jack connector of the laptop?

Are you running these tests in the same room or in different rooms each time?
